# Image box flickers after new image is loaded

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

So i have this code which for every string in the array it adds it the file path and uses it as the file path for the image box, this is the code:

```
 private async void Button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] images = new string[] { "Star_00001.png", "Star_00002.png", "Star_00003.png", "Star_00004.png", "Star_00005.png", "Star_00006.png", "Star_00007.png", "Star_00008.png"};

        string path = "Assets/Star/";

            foreach(string file in images)
            {

            string thepath = Path.Combine(path,file);
            await Task.Delay(46);
            BitmapImage Image = new BitmapImage();
            Image.UriSource = new Uri(this.BaseUri, thepath);
            StarImage.Source = Image;

            }
     }
```

Now everytime the new image is loaded in to the StarImage, it flickers, as far as I know their is no way to stop this because it is the effect of loading a new image in the image box, however does anyone know any alternatives to stop this and give the effect of an animation?

Comment: Is this really about WPF, or are you building a Store App?

Comment: I've edited the question tags. Windows Store Apps don't use WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I think some sort of buffering technique may reduce or eliminate the flickering problem you have.

I've never done this in c#, but essentially you draw to an image which is not yet visible referred to as the buffer, and then make it visible when the image is completely drawn.

[This may help.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you saying to load some of the images in a different image box and make the image box visible when in use and whilst images are loaded into that imagebox load other images in the background to the other imagebox and so on?

Comment: Basically yes.  I'm not exactly sure how to do this in C#. Look for C# techniques for double or triple buffering.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 private async void Button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] images = new string[] { "Star_00001.png", "Star_00002.png", "Star_00003.png", "Star_00004.png", "Star_00005.png", "Star_00006.png", "Star_00007.png", "Star_00008.png" };

        string path = "Assets/Star/";

        foreach (string file in images)
        {

            string thepath = Path.Combine(path, file);
            await Task.Delay(46);

            BitmapImage Image = new BitmapImage();
            Image.BeginInit();
            Image.UriSource = new Uri(this.BaseUri, thepath);
            Image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            Image.EndInit();

            StarImage.Source = Image;

        }
    }
```

Comment: With the BeginInIt(), the CacheOption, the BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad, and the EndInit(); it is asking whether I am missing a reference?

Comment: The answer was (correctly) given for WPF. However, it won't work, because the question didn't actually target WPF, but Store Apps instead.

Comment: @Clemens Ahh I see, that is totally my bad dude! Do you have any answers in mind yourself?

Comment: You may probably attach a handler for the BitmapImage's `ImageOpened` event and do the `StarImage.Source` assignment there.

Answer (score 0):

I've been racking my brains for months trying to solve this, and then I found this post. It helped me solve this! I can't understand for the life of me why Microsoft keeps changing the syntax to do things in windows.

[How to set Background of a Button without flicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226634/how-to-set-background-of-a-button-without-flicker)